# Extracting expression data from GSE dataset downloaded from GEO

Tags: r, bioconductor, microarray, geoquery

I have downloaded [GSE16146](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE16146) dataset from GEO using GEOquery R package.

I would like to extract "Data table" from downloaded GSE16146.

```
>library("GEOquery")
>GSE16146 <- getGEO("GSE16146")
>Table(GSE16146)[1:5,]
```

This returns the following error:

```
> Table(GSE16146)[1:5,]
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Table’ for signature ‘"list"’
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried the function `getGSEDataTables` to access GSE Data Tables from GEO, as reported in this [tutorial](http://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/GEOquery.html)? Also, what version of R/GEOquery are you using?

Comment: GEOquery version 2.42.0, R version 3.4.0  > getGSEDataTables(gset)
Error in as.character.default(<S4 object of class "GSE">) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't calculate a `Table` for a list. Also you might have tried to use `table` instead of `Table`.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [manual](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2011/BioC2011/LabStuff/publicDataTutorial.pdf), all you need to do is:

```
library('GEOquery')
gseGSE16146 <- getGEO('GSE16146', GSEMatrix=FALSE)
```

As explanation, `getGEO()` outputs by default to `GSEMatrix=TRUE` and returns a list of `ExpressionSet` objects. You should get what you were looking for with:

```
Table(GSMList(gseGSE16146)[[1]])[1:5,]
```

The manual has also a paragraph about this:

> The GSE has  a  metadata section, just like the other classes. 
>   However, it doesn’t have a GEODataTable.  Instead, it contains two
>   lists, accessible using GPLList and GSMList, that are each lists of
>   GPL and GSM objects.

I tested the code I posted on `R 3.3.2` and I get access to the Data Table just fine.

update:

Answering how to extract the actual expression data (not what asked in the original question):

```
library(GEOquery) 
data = getGEO("GSE16146") 
datExpr = exprs (data[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Would you suggest how can I extract all the expression matrix for 80 samples (list) from the gseGSE16146?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! What I didn't get is how do I access the actual expression data?

Comment: @Tapper I updated my answer above with how to extract the expression data from the experiment. hope it helps?

Comment: @aechchiki Thank you! The snippet does not contain the data but a list in my case though: GSM4446615 GSM4446616 GSM4446617 GSM4446618. The file getGEO() got was anyway to small to contain the dataset imho. I finally got the data by downloading the big data file myself and processing it with: gse = read.table("GSE123456.txt", sep = "\t"); data=CreateSeuratObject(raw.data = gse, ..) -- What do you think?